# Active Directory User Data Storage

Tags: active-directory, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

What is the best method using MVC4 to store user data for users authenticated with Active Directory?  Should I use SID as the user id?  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE MyStuff AS
{
   ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   AccountDomainSid VARCHAR(50),
   Stuff VARCHAR(100)
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SID` of a user *can* change (e.g. if you merge two domains). That's why there's a [`SIDHistory` attribute on your AD objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), too :-)

See this TechNet blurb on [SID vs. GUID](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961625.aspx).

The one thing that will **always** remain the same is the `objectGUID` from Active Directory - fixed for life.